# Which story is the movie Wandering Earth based upon?

Tags: story-identification, movie, books

I just saw yesterday [The Wandering Earth Project](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7605074/) . While it is a Chinese movie, pretty well-made, this is perhaps the first time I came across the concept of using propellers, earth-engines to push Earth itself to another galaxy.

Which story is this based upon ?

Comment: With friends like these...

Comment: It's an adaptation of a story by Cixin Liu...

Comment: @Mithoron which story ?

Comment: I was thinking of the fleeing Puppeteer worlds in Niven's universe...

Comment: @DavidW Or Earth itself, in *A World Out of Time*, though that was only Earth being moved to orbit Jupiter.

Comment: @DavidW link please of the story 'Fleeing Puppeteer worlds' in Niven's Universe. I haven't heard of that story before.

Comment: @shirish well the fleeing Puppeteer worlds are explained in Niven's novel _Ringworld_ The reason for the fleeing is from his short story "At the Core".

Comment: @shirish *Ringworld*, chapter 5 "Rosette"; a very nice piece of scene-setting even if it permanently confused me as to how to spell "Klemperer." ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The film is based on a short story ("[The Wandering Earth](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13554058-the-wandering-earth)") by Liu Cixin.

> Liu Cixin, the Chinese science fiction writer who wrote the eponymous, responded to the CCTV (China Central Television) interview and answered some questions, many of whom wanted to know the answers.
>
> **Many people cried when they saw this movie. Has this been your case?**
>
> **CL:** *No. I watched this film from the perspective of the creator, not as an ordinary spectator. In some passages, I was thinking about
> how to further improve the effects. In general, the goal is to make
> the plot moving for others. It is hard to be moved by the things we
> have seen many times before.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview with Liu Cixin about The Wandering Earth (in translation)](http://french.china.org.cn/china/txt/2019-02/13/content_74461521.htm)</sup></sub>

He receives a [writing credit](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7605074/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm) as *Cixin Liu*.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the Earth Engines (and the Sun about to explode) are in the short stories but Jupiter and the rest of the film are not.